# How to find unique count of each value from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

How to count the occurrence of each city within a range? I am a beginner to SQL.

I have a table like this:

```
ID  City 
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   B
5   B
6   C
7   D
8   E
9   C
```

Using the SQL query:

```
select `city`
from `table`
where `id` between 3 and 9
```

I am able to extract the city names which lie between the range of 3 and 9.

How can I get the occurrence of each city within the range:

```
City No
A    1
B    2
C    2
D    1
E    1
```

Comment: Go on. Show us as far as you've got. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select city, count(*) as No
from `table`
where id between 3 and 9 
group by city
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but when I run this query, I get the error 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as No

Comment: @learning_always And that's what this code does, no? [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/699d72/1)

Comment: Yes, as per fiddle, your code works perfectly 

But when I am trying to run it using sequel pro, I am getting the error - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as No from `table`
where 
`id` between 3 and 9' at line 1

Any guidance please on how to address it?

Comment: You need to use backticks around `table`

Comment: sorry, I am a novice here. If by backtick you mean 'table' then I am using it

Comment: Yes, like in the above SQL and fiddle

Comment: I am using it exactly as suggested. count(*) is causing the trouble, but I am unable to figure why

Comment: ok it worked when instead of typing count(*) I just wrote cou and selected count(*) from suggestion
Thank you for your time and help. Much appreciated